# How to debug C# process

Tags: c#

I  want to debug two process,(ProcessA.exe and ProcessB.exe)

In the usual scenario, while starting the ProcessA will start ProcessB.  ProcessA is a cross platform exe. ProcessB is C# application.(Visual Studio 2010 Professional).

I did the following for debugging ProcessB (C#)

1. Started ProcessA from C:\Program Files\Test by clicking the exe.
2. ProcessB through Visual Studio 2010 from C:\MyProjects. Attached ProcessA.

In Visual Studio 2010  Attach to Process window:,

Attach to:  as "Managed(v4.) code).

I put the break point in  C# code. But the break point is never getting executed also ProcessB call is not getting executed without debug also(  ie, started all processes from different locations)

Comment: I'm assuming that you have the .pdb files deployed for both processes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool) handles this scenario beautifully.  It works with Visual Studio 2013 on up.

[This blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/) covers some options that must be set, mainly "if you are debugging .NET code, you must choose to **enable mixed mode debugging**", but I recommend reading through the whole post.

Answer (score 1):

If A normally starts B then it seems like you should let A start B then attach visual studio to the B process after it has begun.

Comment: Both ProcessA and ProcessB are independent applications.But I will try you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should attach to **Process B** and not **Process A**

You can try the following:

1. Start ProcessA.exe
2. VS-> Attach to process Window -> attach to **ProcessB.exe**

If you need to debug Process A, this should be done with a seperate VS instance with native debugging.